# Preventing scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is there any way to prevent firing `onscroll` event when setting `scrollTop` property?

```
var a = $(".elem");
a.scrollTop(100); // will fire onScroll
```

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an event, this is function, the only way is to prevent the execution of this line

Comment: Why would you want to set `scrollTop` without it actually **scrolling** to the set *value*? I don't really understand what your after.

Comment: I have two blocks which must scroll each other. When i scroll the first  block the second will be scrolled automatically and vice versa. So i have two different handlers for scroll event. Now events will be called simultaneously but it's not what i need. When the first handler works the second must do nothing.

Comment: By the way, `elem.scrollTop = 10` and `$(elem).scrollTop(10)` work same. Both ways will fire `onscroll` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/d8YLS/) is kind of hackish but it gets the job done:

```
var p1 = $('.one'), p2 = $('.two');
//var lock;
$('p').scroll(function() {
    //if (lock) return;
    //lock = true;
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var other = $(this).hasClass('one') ? p2 : p1;
    other.scrollTop(300 - scrollTop);
    console.log('To:', 300 - scrollTop);
    //lock = false;
});​
```

A basic assumption that we all seem to make is that the events will run *at the same time*, but on closer inspection we realize that Javascript runs on a single thread, meaning they will not run simultaneously. The commented out lock functionality is therefore useless. If you're just trying to synchronize scrolling, the above code should work fine, but I'm honestly not too sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: This causes a feedback loop between the two elements. Firefox chokes on that.